# VimScript: pass value of local variable to edit command

Tags: vim

I have written a simple function to invoke edit command with a path followed by the given filename.

However it looks like `edit l:path` invokes edit for file named `"l:path"` instead of `l:path` variable value. I guess this is a trivial issue, but it's hard to get search results for calling edit command in function, not from the vim editor.

Following code show the proper value of l:path when I change `edit` to `echon`.

```
command! -nargs=1 E call EditAtCurrentPath(<f-args>)

function! EditAtCurrentPath(filename)
    let l:path=expand('%:p:h').'/'.a:filename
    edit l:path
endfunction
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use `:execute` to pass variables to commands:

`execute 'edit' l:path`

There are some good examples in `:help :execute`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: what about if the variable l:path has a '%' , how can you escape it?